# iphone development: how to call a function

Tags: iphone, objective-c, function, methods, method-call

Let us say I have a void function which just have `NSLog(@"Call me");` in its body.

How can I call it in my view like in every ten seconds. I know it sounds like very beginner question but I really need it

Comment: read about NSTimer which does exactly what you're looking for. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html

Comment: This question is so far away from the OP being able to use NSTimer that they are not helpful suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(yourMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Comment: It is OK but I want it to stop it after 5 iterations. However it goes to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

Use NSTimer class 
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(makeMyProgressBarMoving) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]